# Close votes review tasks and close votes directly on the question: different counters?

Tags: support, review, closing, badges

When we do a "close vote" review task, then this increase the counter by one (and we get a badge when the counter reaches $250$ for example). However, when we decide to vote to close by clicking directly under the question this counter is not increased. Is there a special reason for that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Fundamental Thank for the resizing, I tried and wasn't successful.

Comment: See: [Rescaling images after posting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10715/rescaling-images-after-posting/10862#10862).

Answer (score 5):

Yes. The counter is for close vote **reviews**: it gets increased when you review questions in the close vote queues. It doesn't increase when you vote to close a question in the wild. Note that it is also increased if you do anything else like "Leave Open" or "Edit", you don't necessarily have to vote to close. In fact the same badge exists for all review queues and counts reviews tasks.

Comment: Ok, but my question is: "why such a choice?"

Comment: @Surb  The purpose of the badge is to encourage reviewing (as opposed to closing). To make this more clear: Do you mean to propose to increase the counter for every vote to close or just for every vote to close on a question that happens to be in review already?

Comment: @quid This looks like a very good reason to me (not encouraging closing but reviewing). "Do you mean to propose to increase the counter for every vote to close or just for every vote to close on a question that happens to be in review already? " I was wondering for both honestly. I discover always more how amazingly well thought this website is done and was not suggesting anything, just interested to understand.